# Can't use Get-Service –ComputerName on remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, virtualbox

I have a windows 2003 box setup with virtual box and I can't powershell to work with it.

I try this on my windows 7 machine

```
Get-Service –ComputerName myserver
```

I get back

```
Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'myserver'. This operation might require other privileges.
At Script1.ps1:2 char:4
+ gsv <<<<  -cn myserver
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

While searching around I found I should try and use `Enable-PSRemoting`.

I did this and now when I try to use it I get

> WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine. WinRM
>   already is set up for remote management on this machine.

Yet I still get the same error. Is this because I am using a virtual machine? I setup the virtual OS to be on my domain and I can even use my AD account credentials to log in.

I can get other information back from it.

So it is not like I can't connect to it with powershell.

Comment: The accepted answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868178/why-would-a-get-process-computername-return-a-couldnt-connect-to-remote-machin) might be of some help.

Comment: Ya not sure I went to that article but I keep getting "The RPC server is unavailable" everything I tried so far as failed to get rid of this error.

Comment: Firewall is active on server? have you tried with firewall off?

Comment: Ya firewall is off. I actually turned them off on both computers.

Comment: I have  same your issue if I run powershell with user with no administration credentials of remote server. Have you try run powershell with domain admin credentials or at least put in "administrators" local group of remote server your domain user? this will do the trick.

Comment: Can you give an example? the virtual box vm was put to me on the corporate network so I don't have that admin account. The virtual box vm does have a admin account that I can log into is that what your talking about?

Comment: @chobo2 You have administrative credentials for the remote server?

Comment: Well I the admin account and I added my domain username and password as admin to the remote server as well. It is just a test vm with windows 2003 that I made to test stuff in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With PowerShell V2 you've got two approachs for remote commands.

**Commands with built-in remoting :**

A small set of commands in PowerShell v2 have a `-ComputerName` parameter, which allows you to specify the target machine to access.

```
Get-Process
Get-Service
Set-Service

Clear-EventLog
Get-Counter
Get-EventLog
Show-EventLog
Limit-EventLog
New-EventLog
Remove-EventLog
Write-EventLog

Restart-Computer
Stop-Computer

Get-HotFix
```

These commands do their own remoting either because the underlying infrastructure already supports remoting or they address scenarios that are of particular importance to system management. They are built on the top of DCOM and, on the access point of view, you can use them when you can establish a session with the remote machine with commands like `NET.exe` or `PSExec.exe`.

You are trying to use one of them and you've got a problem with credentials (`-cred` parameter), because your token credentials can't be used to establish an admin session to the remote machine.

**The PowerShell remoting subsystem :**

Before you can use PowerShell remoting to access a remote computer, the remoting service on that computer has to be explicitly enabled. You do so using the `Enable-PSRemoting` cmdlet. If you are working in workgroup you also need to enable the server to enter on your client computer with this command (on your client computer as administrator):

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *
```

Then, you will use `New-PSSession` Cmdlet (with `-computername` and `-credentials`) to create a session object. Then `Invoke-Command` (with `-session` and `-scriptblock`) cmdlet allows you to remotely invoke a scriptblock on another computer. This is the base element for most of the features in remoting. You can also use Enter-PSSession to establish an interactive (SSL like) PowerShell command line with the server.

Useful link : [Layman’s guide to PowerShell 2.0 remoting](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1305)

---

Test this :

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName myServer-Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {get-service}
...
Remove-PSSession -Session $sess
```

Comment: Ok it tried to do these instructions in the book but still does not work. I am not sure if this has to do with the fact that even thought the computer is on my domain I can't access shared folders or anything like that. I never had to do anything to other computers on my domain to get remoting working but they are real servers and not a virtual one.

Comment: When I do this though.  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myserver Set-Service -Name 'IISAdmin' Name -sttus 'stopped'. It works. I tried this just in a powershell console. So do I have to consistently do this? in my scripts I write? If so why do some computers don't need this and other do. As you can see I am very confused.

Comment: No ! You have to create a session with New-PSSession, and then use Invoke-Command -session yoursession -scriptblock {your code}. Please read carefully the doc !

Comment: So I would just make on session then use invoke-command. I guess as you said there are only a limited amount of commands that support -ComputerName so I probably will have to make a session in my script I am making. I still don't understand why -ComputerName does not work.

Comment: Anyway around not using scriptblock as well? I am looking at it and it just seems messy.

Answer (score 4):

If it is still important, here is my workaround:

I got an unprivileged user called 'usser' who wants powershell(v2) remoting from  client A to server B.

Steps:

1. *enable-psremoting* on Targetserver B as admin
2. *Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI* on Targetserver B as admin
3. Add "usser" with full privileges

Now comes the exciting part:

4. *sc sdshow scmanager* on Targetserver B as admin
5. Copy the SDDL output
6. sc sdset scmanager (f.e.:)"D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)"  , in the Output you have to fill after this part ***(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)*** this = (A;;KA;;;*SID*)
7. *SID* stands of course for the SID of the unprivileged "usser"-user
8. when everything should be fine, it will similiar looks like this :

   D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;S-1-5-21-4233383628-1788409597-1873130553-1161)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)

Hope you will enjoy that little but complicated workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Viewing and manipulating services requires administrative privileges on the target machine.

I was able to duplicate your error message by attempting to run `Get-Service -ComputerName MyServer` while logged in as a user account that doesn't have administrative rights to the server in question.

You can resolve this by either granting the workstation user account administrative privileges on the target server or by creating a a local group on the server and granting invocation privileges to members of that group. If you want to do the latter, see the following article.

[msgoodies: Using a PS Session without having Administrative Permissions](http://msgoodies.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-ps-session-without-having.html)

Comment: My user account that I setup should have admin privileges. How can I verify this just to make sure.

Comment: On the server, run `net localgroup Administrators` to list the local administrators on that server.

Comment: I just got a chance to check now(the vm is on my work computer). I am an admin so I should have the correct permissions. I guess it is still some other problem.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @scusi marcus's brilliant answer here:

Let's say I have an unprivileged/limited user called 'user1' who wants powershell(v2+) remoting from client machine A to targetserver B.

Steps:

1. From elevated powershell prompt on targetserver B, run `enable-psremoting`.  Accept several Y/N dialog confirmations or else run with `-force` switch.
2. In same elevated prompt as step 1, *Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI*
3. In the resulting dialog, add "user1". *Read* privileges should be sufficient unless you are planning on remotely manipulating services, in which case you will want *Full Control*.
4. On targetserver B, from an elevated (non-powershell) prompt or as an administrator, run `sc sdshow scmanager`. Copy the SDDL output. May look something like this: `D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)`

> UPDATE: If we add the limited user to the target computer's Remote Management Users group, we can add `(A;;LCRPWPDTLO;;;RM)` to the `D:` portion of the above SDDL string, and skip steps 5 and 6 below.

5. Determine the SID of the underprivileged user account (in our case, "user1"). (Hint: try `wmic useraccount where name='user1' get sid`)
6. Insert the following text into the output we copied in step 5: `(A;;KA;;;*SID*)` where *SID* is the SID of the user determined in step 5. Insert it somewhere in a place before the `S:` part of the SDDL string retrieved in step 4. So now you should have a string looking something like this: `D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;S-1-5-21-4233383628-1788409597-1873130553-1161)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)`
7. On targetserver B, run `sc sdset scmanager` followed by our new modified SDDL string. So the entire command would look something like this: 
   `sc sdset scmanager D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;S-1-5-21-4233383628-1788409597-1873130553-1161)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)`

You should now be able to remotely access the Service Control Manager on the remote server while logged into client machine A as "user1".

On client machine A, you may find that when you run `Get-Service –ComputerName remoteserver` not all services are listed. You may need to repeat the above process (starting at step 4) for a specific service that you need remote access to, but which is not listed in your `Get-Service` output on client machine A. For instance, if the *sqlserveragent* service is not listed (but you know it is present on the targetserver), you would again log in to targetserver B and execute `sc sdshow` but this time not for *scmanager* but for the *sqlserveragent* service, so `sc sdshow sqlserveragent`. You would again receive some SDDL output that would need to be manipulated as above. At this point, it may be worth learning more about SDDL (Google it - this [link](https://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/) was helpful for me), with the main *caveat* to watch for the `D:` and `S:` portions of the SDDL string and make sure you aren't messing with the `S:` part.

Comment: Powershell (v5+?) now has a cmdlet that will parse out this SDDL stuff into human comprehensible output: `ConvertFrom-SDDLString <SDDLstring>`

Answer (score 1):

I know that this isn't the ideal answer to this question, but I was having a similar issue trying to use PowerShell to talk to a Windows 7 box.  Turns out, WMI hadn't been installed with the native PSv2 that comes with Win7.

As soon as I installed v3 as part of the WMI 3.0 package, the problem solved itself.  I'd suggest making sure that all the relevant WMI services are running on your server.  Unless you have conflicts, I'd also recommend upgrading to WMI 3.0.