# Running Powershell commands/script from remote client machine fails but locally works

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

These are the commands i am trying to execute.

> $credential = get-credential
>
> $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName win-j1uti0rc7xx -Credential $credential
>
> invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Add-PSSNapin *exchange* ; Get-Mailbox }

If i run these command on server (where exchange server is deployed) I will get desired output. But if i run same commands on client (Win 7) i would hit below error.

> Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'Test\Administrator' is invalid.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ADInvalidCredentialException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=WIN-J1UTI0RC7QP,RequestId=17684af8-031d-4511-8142-a3ef49783620,TimeStamp=12/24/2
>      018 5:30:37 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADInvalidCredentialException] 3B308A1A
>       + PSComputerName        : win-j1uti0rc7xx

I have enabled PSRemote, set execution policy remotesigned, added client to trustedhosts on server. Anything else i am missing ?

By the way i think only for exchange cmdlets i am getting these errors. Because if i call

> Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Culture}

I am getting desired output in both machines.

Comment: Remoting to an Exchange server is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Why do you need to use remote PowerShell on the server itself? Can't you just use `Add-PSSNapin exchange ; Get-Mailbox` right away?

Comment: @GabrielLuci , I dont need remote powershell on server. In example i showed that it's working in server, but failing when run from remote client.

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld.. I have tried that as well.. If i use Kerberos it says : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos
authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.                                                                                                                 If i use basic authentication it says   : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not
available...

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell V2 you've got two approachs for remote commands.

Please refer to the below link:

[Can't use Get-Service –ComputerName on remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744903/cant-use-get-service-computername-on-remote-computer)