# Get SQL Services details without administrator permissions

Tags: sql, powershell, wmi, winrm, get-wmiobject

Unable to fetch SQL services without administrator permissions

I tried below script to fetch services
Get-Ciminstance -className win32_Service -OperationTimeoutSec 15 -ComputerName ‘xyz’

I got access denied error

For resolving above issue

1. I have granted Remote Management Users to my account
2. Given permission to class_32_Service to my account

After granting above permissions i am able to see services remotely with non admin account. Unfortunately i am not able to see SQL services as the need of own sddl permissions rights

Due to security issues i am unable to set sddl rights.

Hence is there any other solution to get the SQL services details without administrator rights.

Comment: No.  The only services you can see are the ones in Event viewer which are the system processes and the current user processes.  Not other users services.  Not sure but if you could start the services as the System Account you will be able to see the services

Comment: Could you suggest any other method to fetch the SQL service without administrator permissions

Comment: The only workaround that exists is quite complicated: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888400/14720063